# Partial derivative with respect to a sum

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose there are functions $J = f(\sum_k y_k)$ and $y_k = g(x)$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Now suppose I want to apply the chain rule to calculate the partial derivative of $J$ w.r.t. $x$. I.e.,

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial (\sum_k y_k)} \frac{\partial (\sum_k y_k)}{\partial x}.
\end{equation}

Because the partial derivative is a linear map, we can indeed write the second term in the right as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \sum_k y_k}{\partial y} = \sum_k \frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x} 
\end{equation}
which is standard notation.

But what about the first term $\frac{\partial J}{\partial (\sum_k y_k)}$ on the right?

Does the partial derivative w.r.t. a sum make sense?

If it does, what is the result?

If it does not, why?

Comment: Do you mean $y_k = g_k(x)$ for each $k$?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

One is that you’re taking a partial derivative with respect to one variable $x$ without specifying which other variables you’re regarding as independent of $x$ and keeping constant. That’s not entirely your fault; our suboptimal notation for partial derivatives makes it easy to do that. As long as you don’t have any other variables that you want to treat as independent of $x$, you should just write a normal (total) derivative.

The second problem is that you seem to be confusing formal arguments and actual arguments. The function $f$ takes one formal argument (for which you haven’t introduced a name). The actual argument, i.e. the value that you substitute for the formal argument in this specific case, is $\sum_ky_k$. Derivatives (both total and partial) are taken with respect to the formal arguments, not with respect to the actual arguments. A conventional way to write this would be to introduce a name for the formal argument of the function $f$, say $f:z\mapsto f(z)$, and then write

$$
\frac{\mathrm dJ}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f\left(\sum_ky_k\right)=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dz}\left(\sum_ky_k\right)\cdot\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\sum_ky_k\right)=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dz}\left(\sum_ky_k\right)\cdot\sum_k\frac{\mathrm dy_k}{\mathrm dx}\;.
$$

Having said all that, people do sometimes write things like

$$
\frac{\mathrm df(abx)}{\mathrm d(ab)}\;.
$$

or

$$
\frac{\mathrm df\left(\sum_ky_k\right)}{\mathrm d\left(\sum_ky_k\right)}\;.
$$

That’s OK as long as you know what you’re doing and it’s clear to everyone what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for the great exposition. Unfortunately, it does not completely answer neither the main question nor any of the "subquestions". It does answer to some extent the second subquestion, though.

Comment: @neoglez: I'm sorry to hear that. Perhaps I misunderstood the questions. In short, I thought I implicitly gave the following answers to your questions: Q: "But what about the first term on the right?" A: That term is not standard notation. Q: "Does the partial derivative w.r.t. a sum make sense?" A: It doesn't; by definition a sum can only be an actual argument and not a formal argument. Q: "If it does not, why?" A: I tried to explain that by pointing out the distinction between formal and actual arguments. (This is in response to your original comment before you added the last sentence.)

Comment: Now, this comment is enlightening. Would you consider editing the answer to clarify and succinctly present the arguments, like in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

It helps me to use variables for the intermediate derivatives in a chain rule computation, rather than the function names. Let the functions be called $f(t)$ and $y_k(x)$, so $J(x) = f(y_1(x) + \dots + y_n(x)$. If you write it this way, you can see a single-variable-calculus derivation of the derivative.

However, let us use the multivariable chain rule to verify. We have
$$
    \frac{dJ}{dx} = \sum_k \frac{df}{dt} \frac{\partial t}{\partial y_k} \frac{dy_k}{dx}
$$
If $t = y_1 + \dots y_k$, then $\frac{\partial t}{\partial y_k} = 1$. So
$$
\frac{dJ}{dx} = \frac{df}{dt} \sum_k \frac{dy_k}{dx}
$$
In Newtonian notation,
$$
    J'(x) = f'(g_1(x) + \dots + g_n(x))(g_1'(x) + \dots + g_n'(x))
$$